# Replacement character in SQL database

Tags: sql, replace, character

I have a table in database containing 50000 records, but in column `slno` around 20000 rows contain `/` and I want to replace this character with `-`.

Example :

```
34158/256
```

Output

```
34158-256
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with the `replace()` function.  As an `update`:

```
update t
    set slno = replace(slno, '/', '-')
    where slno like '%/%';
```

(The `where` is optional here, but makes the logic explicit.)

You can also just do this in a `select` statement as:

```
select replace(slno, '/', '-')
from table t;
```

Comment: Assuming the rdbms he is using has such a function.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . Can you name a database that doesn't have `replace()`?